# How get Instance in Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to update a model in Django using the class-based generic view UpdateView.But i have some instance problem.When i click submit button id is  pass to update form , but instances isn't

i am new in django ,so please be forgiving if I'm doing something stupid.

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'inventory'
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

url(r'^inventory/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.HardwareDelete.as_view(), name='hardware-delete'),
url(r'^inventory/update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.HardwareUpdate.as_view(), name='hardware-update'),
# url(r'^/inventory/add$', views.InventoryAdd.as_view(), name='add-inventory'),]
```

**models.py**

```
class Hardwares(models.Model):
    hardware_unit=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    hardware_model=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    hardware_subsystem=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    hardware_serial_number=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    hardware_manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    hardware_operating_system = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    hardware_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])

    def get_absolute_url( self ):
        return reverse('inventory:index')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hardware_serial_number+"  "+self.hardware_model+"  "+self.hardware_unit+"  "+str(self.hardware_quantity)
```

**forms.py**

```
class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    hardware_unit = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Hardware Unit Name..', }))
    hardware_model = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Model Name...', }))
    hardware_subsystem = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', }))
    hardware_serial_number = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', }))
    hardware_manufacturer = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Manufacturer Company Name', }))
    hardware_operating_system = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Operating System Name', }))
    hardware_quantity = forms.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)],
    widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Quantity of Harware', }))

    class Meta:
        model = Hardwares
        fields = {'hardware_unit', 'hardware_model', 'hardware_subsystem', 'hardware_serial_number',
              'hardware_manufacturer', 'hardware_operating_system', 'hardware_quantity', }
```

**views.py**

```
class HardwareUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Hardwares
    template_name = 'inventory/update_form.html'
    form_class = HardwareForm
```

**update.form html**

```
{% extends 'inventory/basic_menu.html' %}
{% block body %}

                <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post"
                      enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Hardware
                            Unit</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            {{ form.hardware_unit }}

                            <span class="help-block">Hardware Unit Name eg.:  Firewall , Notebook , Phone</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
             //Have more 8 form groups like this

{% endblock body %}
```

Here is some part of my update_form.html .The rest part is the same

## SOLUTION

Problem occured from my update button form's method.its method was "post".I change it to "get" method and problem solved.Don't need to overried Updateview post function.Thanks to all for solutions.

> **BEFOR**
>
> ```
>         <form action="{% url 'inventory:hardware-update' hardwares.id %}"
>         method="post" style="display: inline;">
>                             {% csrf_token %}...........
> ```
>
> **AFTER**
>
> ```
>         <form action="{% url 'inventory:hardware-update' hardwares.id %}"
>         method="get" style="display: inline;">
>                             {% csrf_token %}...........
> ```

Comment: Please show your template

Comment: I updated the question and add  some part of my template.

Comment: did you override get method?

Comment: No, i didnt.i think dont need to override get method.i search same examples about updateview and i didnt see override get method in examples

Comment: As an aside, it would be better to use a list `[...]` rather than a set `{...}` for `fields` in your form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't usually need to override `post` for generic class based views. The class based view will take care of fetching the instance if you simplify it to:

```
class HardwareUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Hardwares
    form_class = HomeForm
    template_name = 'inventory/update_form.html'
```

You don't need to add `instance` to the template context. The update view will automatically adds it, so you can use `{{ object }}` or `{{ hardwares }}` in the template (`hardwares` is a bit confusing because it's a single object -- it would be better to follow the Django recommendation and name your model `Hardware`)

Comment: my updateView work clearly andi can get instance in other project.but when i create forms and add some forms attrs i get this problem.i think this is originate from forms.py

Comment: Try to narrow down where the problem is. Does it work if you simplify the template to use `{{ form }}`? Does it work if you remove `form_class = HomeForm` and use the automatically generated form?

Comment: @khayyam_islamzadeh how did you solve the problem in the end?

Comment: when i remove form_class . it get "fields" error and after i define fields in HardwareUpdate class..This time form fields is shown but instances not.

Comment: When i define fields {{object.hardware_unit}} , it show their instance but this time fields dont

Comment: In the template, `{{ object }}` is the model instance and `{{ form }}` is form. If you do `{{ object.hardware_unit }}` that should show the value of the object. It isn't meant to show the form field. You would use `{{ form.hardware_unit }}` for that.